# Wordpress:500 internal server error after changing url

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

My domain (`example.com`) is pointed to `public_html/cushbu`   it contains a wordpress project

so i've changed the settings in `wp-config` file

```
 define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
  define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Also in `.htaccess` file thats under `pubic_html/cushbu` folder

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example.com
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example.com/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


# Wordfence WAF

<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>

# END Wordfence WAF

#disable hotlinking of images with forbidden or custom image option
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ – [NC,F,L]
```

I got 500 error when accessing my domain (`www.example.com`)

Comment: change RewriteBase /example.com to RewriteBase /cushbu

Comment: also change RewriteRule  /cushbu/index.php [L]

Comment: Nop still the same error

Comment: RewriteBase / and RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: it didn't worked again the same 500 error

Comment: ok. remove .htaccess and login to wp-admin and go to Settings-> Permalink-> Save Changes

Comment: yeahh its worked

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147030/discussion-between-shital-marakana-and-jabaa).

Answer (score 1):

Remove `example.com` in .htaccess from the `RewriteBase` and `RewriteRule`.
It is probably easiest for you to rename the file to `bck.htaccess` and let wordpress generate a new one for you.

Comment: see the comments by @shital-marakana, that is ecxatly the same as my answer.